# How to make the player's image in front of another image?

Tags: python, windows, image, pygame

I have this code that runs fine but the only problem is that the player's image is behind the other images so you can't see where the player is. How do I make it so the player's image is in front of that image like a background layer. And how do I also make other images appear behind the other background images. Like for example I have this background tree:

```
class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('tree.png')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

And I have the player's class:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('mapMover.png')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def changespeed_x(self,x):
        self.change_x = x

    def changespeed_y(self,y):
        self.change_y = y

    def update(self, barrier_list, Upcar_list, Downcar_list):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        barrier_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, barrier_list, False)
        Upcar_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, Upcar_list, False)
        Downcar_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, Downcar_list, False)

        for barrier in barrier_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = barrier.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = barrier.rect.right

        for Upcar in Upcar_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = Upcar.rect.left
                Upcar.rect.x += 3
            else:
                self.rect.left = Upcar.rect.right
                Upcar.rect.x -= 3
            return

        for Downcar in Downcar_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = Downcar.rect.left
                Downcar.rect.x += 3
            else:
                self.rect.left = Downcar.rect.right
                Downcar.rect.x -= 3
            return

        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        barrier_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, barrier_list, False)
        Upcar_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, Upcar_list, False)
        Downcar_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, Downcar_list, False)

        for barrier in barrier_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = barrier.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = barrier.rect.bottom

        for Upcar in Upcar_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.top = Upcar.rect.bottom
                Upcar.rect.y += 3
            else:
                self.rect.bottom = Upcar.rect.top
                Upcar.rect.x -= 3
            return

        for Downcar in Downcar_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.top = Downcar.rect.bottom
                Downcar.rect.y += 3
            else:
                self.rect.bottom = Downcar.rect.top
                Downcar.rect.x -= 3
            return
```

Python 2.6, Pygame Sprites, Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above, you're drawing/blitting the player first, and then the background, in the mainloop.

Wrong:

```
while not done: # The main loop, it may be different in your code.

    player.draw() 
    background.draw() # What you're probably doing.
```

Right:

```
while not done: # The main loop, it may be different in your code.

    background.draw() # What you should do.
    player.draw()
```

To be sure, just draw the background, no matter how you've implemented it, RIGHT AFTER the beginning of the main-loop's block. If you're updating/drawing your game in a separate procedure like:

```
def update():
    background.draw() # What you should do.
    player.draw()

while not done:
    update()
```

BE SURE that you're drawing the background in the separate function before anything. Remember: BACKground, you should always draw it "at the back" of anything (previously/before) :).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show the relevant code, but the issue is clear:

The `Surface` you blittet last to the screen is "on top". If you first draw your player sprite, and then your background image on top of it, you'll only the background image.

So you either have to draw your sprites in the right order, or, since you use the `Sprite` class, but your sprites into a [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) group and give them a `_layer` attribute.